# iPhone 4s is not responding at all

Tags: ios, hardware, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s, and at the moment, my phone is going through alot of issues. I haven't been able to charge my phone, due to the phone not responding or not reacting to the cable. My phone also will not turn on or attempt to charge. The Battery sign comes up but not the charging sign. Is it a battery problem?

Comment: Does it show something like "Not Charging"? Can you connect it to iTunes successfuly?

Comment: Check this article, to troubleshoot this issue ; https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412

Answer (score 1):

It could be the battery.  The phone is 3-4 years old.  However it could also be the charging cable or the port.  The battery symbol with a sliver of red just means the battery has no charge.

If you can, try using other charging cables to see if those are more successful in charging the phone.

If different cables don't work, then try cleaning the contacts in the charging port.  Those can get dirty or corrode over time.  Try some of the tips here to clean the port: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/use-a-toothpick-to-clean-out-your-iphone/

If none of those work, you should look to try to replace the battery.  Apple can do this and there are 3rd party services like iFix that will charge $40 or so to replace the battery.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a bit. It's likely a charging port issue. Try giving it a clean as above, or maybe you can take it in for a fix, though that may run you something like $80.